# fail to open link in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Fail to open link in webview in android. I tried it in webview but it only shows blank page. It seems that some of urls are loaded but some not how is it.

```
String strUrl =  "https://app.mygtechguy.com/5862bd814bf7f"; 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oh no! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Make sure internet is working well");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().getAllowContentAccess();
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(strUrl);
```

Comment: Are you given a Internet permission in manifest.???

Comment: Probably you wanted to use `setAllowContentAccess()` instead of `getAllowContentAccess()`

Comment: yes #Dileep_Patel , some urls open but this one is not open check it at your side.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try to remove the url loading from shouldOverrideUrlLoading like this:

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
```

And also in the AndroidManifest.xml set Internet permission:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Still not working, it shows a blank after loading progress. permission is ok in AndroidManifest.xml. because some urls are open normally but this one is not. check it at your side in sample app if you have time, Thank you

Comment: Try to put all your settings before loading like this:

`webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true); webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY); webView.loadUrl(strUrl); webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  ...... `

Notice the correction of **set**AllowContentAccess(**true**);

Comment: Dear Johny, Its still not working, can you test it at yourside in sample app

Comment: @sajid45 I already test it and it loads successfully. It just takes some time to load.